# Problems when extracting attributes from an XML file using R

Tags: xml, r

I'm having problems trying to extract data from an XML file (the data is stored as attributes and not as elements, if I'm right). I'm using R 3.1.2 on Windows 7 with RStudio.

The file (shortened) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<MensajePredicionesEolicas>
 <CodElemento Zona="Espana">
  <PotInstalada valor="22751000" /> 
   <FechaFichero valor="2014120907" /> 
   <Detalle>
    <FechaDato valor="2014-12-09">
     <HoraDato valor="7">
      <Prediccion valor="10588564" /> 
      <Percentil10 valor="9563875" /> 
      <Percentil90 valor="11435276" /> 
     </HoraDato>
     <HoraDato valor="8">
      <Prediccion valor="10269849" /> 
      <Percentil10 valor="8588400" /> 
      <Percentil90 valor="11623841" /> 
     </HoraDato>
     <HoraDato valor="9">
      <Prediccion valor="9823678" /> 
      <Percentil10 valor="7840628" /> 
      <Percentil90 valor="11536093" /> 
     </HoraDato>
    </FechaDato>
   </Detalle>
 </CodElemento>
</MensajePredicionesEolicas>
```

For example, to extract the values of the atrribute FechaDato I've tried:

```
data <- xmlParse("file.xml")
date.pred.path <- "//CodElemento[@Zona='Espana']/Detalle/FechaDato"
date.pred <- sapply(data[date.pred.path], xmlGetAttr, "FechaDato")
```

I'm obtaining empty lists. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no XML attribute called "FechaDato". Are you trying to extract the "valor" attribute? `date.pred <- sapply(data[date.pred.path], xmlGetAttr, "valor")`

Comment: As @MrFlick commented "FechaDato" is the `node`.  The only attribute of "FechaData" is "valor".  If you do 

`xmlApply(data[date.pred.path],xmlAttrs)`

you can see the difference between a `node` and an `attribute`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the XML parser get confused when reaches CodElemento and afterwards Detalle. However, I managed to extract the information by applying xmlToList.

```
xmlText <- c('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<MensajePredicionesEolicas>
 ...
</MensajePredicionesEolicas>')

library(XML)

#Parse the XML
data  <- xmlTreeParse(xmlText)

#Access to the root element (MensajePredicionesEolicas)
MPE <- xmlRoot(doc)

#Access to CodElemento and apply xmlToList function to obtain the data
(MPE <- xmlApply(MPE,xmlToList))
```

Result:

```
$CodElemento
$CodElemento$PotInstalada
     valor 
"22751000" 

$CodElemento$FechaFichero
       valor 
"2014120907" 

$CodElemento$Detalle
       FechaDato   
       "10588564"  
       "9563875"   
       "11435276"  
       "7"         
       "10269849"  
       "8588400"   
       "11623841"  
       "8"         
       "9823678"   
       "7840628"   
       "11536093"  
       "9"         
.attrs "2014-12-09"

$CodElemento$.attrs
    Zona 
"Espana"
```

You can know extract the FechaDato data by using:

```
MPE$CodElemento$Detalle
```

Unfortunatelly, It loses the name of the paramaters (Prediccion, Percentil10, Percentil90)...